# When to add a sequence of fields in a materialized view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Good evening,

I am trying to understand in which cases the sequence would be used, for the example below, since the rowids would not always give me a single row to manage the changes.

Why consider a sequence of additional fields?

I will be grateful if you could clarify the doubt, with some example.

Thank you so much,

Greetings.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON sales 
   WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(amount_sold, time_id, prod_id)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now imagine that you want to create a materialized view that contains aggregates on this table. Because the materialized view log has been created with all referenced columns in the materialized view's defining query, the materialized view is fast refreshable. If DML is applied against the sales table, then the changes are reflected in the materialized view when the commit is issued.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sum_sales
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS  
SELECT s.time_id, COUNT(*) AS count_grp,
   SUM(s.amount_sold) AS sum_dollar_sales,
   COUNT(s.amount_sold) AS count_dollar_sales
FROM sales s
GROUP BY s.time_id;
```

Without using the sequence, you will have the following error

```
ORA-12033: cannot use filter columns from materialized view log on "ADMIN"."SALES"
```

So let me try to explain why, by using a **Testcase**

```
drop table sales;
create table sales (time_id number, prod_id number, amount_sold number)
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON sales 
   WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(amount_sold, time_id, prod_id)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES; 

truncate table sales;
insert into sales values (1,1,23);
insert into sales values (1,2,23);
commit;

select time_id, sum(amount_sold) from sales group by time_id;

TIME_ID SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) 
------- ---------------- 
      1               46
```

Now Imagine, that you will modify a row multiple times.

```
update sales set amount_sold = 55 where time_id = 1 and PROD_ID = 1;
update sales set amount_sold = 12 where time_id = 1 and PROD_ID = 1;

select time_id, sum(amount_sold) from sales group by time_id;
TIME_ID SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) 
------- ---------------- 
      1               35
```

your new amount_sold is 35. **How to do** a fast refresh without reading the value for the row (1,2) because you only modified (1,1)

```
select * from MLOG$_SALES where DMLTYPE$$ != 'I' order by ;

AMOUNT_SOLD TIME_ID PROD_ID M_ROW$$            SEQUENCE$$ SNAPTIME$$           DMLTYPE$$ OLD_NEW$$ CHANGE_VECTOR$$            XID$$ 
----------- ------- ------- ------------------ ---------- -------------------- --------- --------- --------------- ---------------- 
         23       1       1 AAAwaSAAAAAAFpTAAA        105 4000-01-01T00:00:00Z U         U         CA==            4222223434942993 
         55       1       1 AAAwaSAAAAAAFpTAAA        106 4000-01-01T00:00:00Z U         N         CA==            4222223434942993 
         55       1       1 AAAwaSAAAAAAFpTAAA        107 4000-01-01T00:00:00Z U         U         CA==            4222223434942993 
         12       1       1 AAAwaSAAAAAAFpTAAA        108 4000-01-01T00:00:00Z U         N         CA==            4222223434942993
```

So you can use the previous value 46 and increment/decrement using the old/new value as follow

```
select 46 - 23 + 55  - 55 + 12 as newval from dual;

NEWVAL 
------ 
    35
```

You can also do the same when doing a delete

This is not possible having only the rowid. To generate the new value 35 you need to read an unmodified value, so you cannot do a fast refresh.

Hope that this can help you to understand in which cases the sequence is used

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation was very good.